# Python Pandas how to get nearest date to a given date

Tags: python, pandas

```
   date
0  09-2019
1  10-2019
2  11-2019
4  01-2020
5  02-2020
7  04-2020
```

I have a pandas dataframe `dates` like the above - this isn't ordered in any way. I set the dates column as datetime type and select the month and year only like so:

```
dates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['date'], errors='ignore')
dates['date'] = dates['date'].dt.strftime("%m-%Y")
```

I want to select the row which has the nearest date to a given one, which I'm setting like so:

```
latest_date = max(dates['date'])
latest_date = latest_date.strftime("%m-%Y")
```

This gives me `05-2020`. How do I use the `nearest` method to select the date from `dates` which is **nearest** or **equal** to `latest_date`? The expected output from the example should be `04-2020`.

I've tried this:

```
dates.iloc[dates.index.get_loc(datetime.datetime(latest_date),method='nearest')]
```

But I get a `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`. Does this mean that I'm not correctly converting the dates column?

Comment: have a look at [asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `idxmin` on the difference between the column and the said `latest_date`:

```
latest_date = '05-2020'
print (dates.loc[(pd.to_datetime(dates['date'])
                  -pd.to_datetime(latest_date)).abs().idxmin(), 
                 'date'])
'04-2020'
```

Comment: Nice! And I understand what it does :)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat : it is much safer and results more assured, if the index is sorted

```
#set 'date' as index
df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['date']).set_index('date')

#get the nearest date : 
df.index.sort_values().asof('05-2020')
Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00')
```